# Primefaces selectOneMenu displaying &nbsp; when label is empty

Tags: javascript, primefaces

For some reason selectOneMenu is showing `&nbsp;` when selecting an option with an empty label.

When first loading the page, it works fine, but if I select the blank option in my list, it displays `&nbsp;`

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="eyeColor" editable="true" value="#{model.eyeColor}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel=" " value="#{null}"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{selectionList.getSelectList(SelectListDefinition.SELECT_EYE_COLOR)}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

any idea what could be causing this?

and how to fix it?

Comment: Does `itemLabel=""` giving the same result?

Comment: yes, if I put `""` it is actually worse, it displays `@nbsp;` when the page is first loaded

Comment: I can help you about removing it but I don't know what is the reason of the problem.

Comment: what are you suggesting?

Comment: `$(".ui-selectonemenu-items li:nth-child(1)").html($(".ui-selectonemenu-items li:nth-child(1)").html().replace(/&nbsp;/gi,''));`
can work. put this into `document.ready` function.

Comment: I just found out that `itemLabel="&#160;"` works... go figure

Comment: JavaScript is responsible for that, not JSF. Report this as p:selectOneMenu issue to PrimeFaces guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved by the Primefaces team (actually it seems like the bug has been previously fixed and resurfaced in later versions):

[Official bug description](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=5624)

The fix is already available since version 3.5.9 for Primefaces Elite users (a subscription service with a monthly cost), and should be generally available when version 4.0 is released (which will be free and open source):

[Primefaces Downloads](http://www.primefaces.org/downloads.html)

There is also a small discussion about this on the [Primefaces Forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=28834).

*Edit: Since October 3 2013, this fix is available free as community release 4.0: [Primefaces Blog](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2918)*

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for reviving this old post.

I was working on an old project and we were unable to upgrade the PF version.

The fix is pretty simple, indeed.
It also fixes HTML entities showing as plain text instead of their representation.

Just need to create a javascript patch:

```
// Fixes HTML Select Label
PrimeFaces.widget.SelectOneMenu = PrimeFaces.widget.SelectOneMenu.extend({
    setLabel: function(a) {
        this._super(a);
        if (!this.cfg.editable) {
            this.label.html(a)
        } else {
            if (a.trim().toLowerCase() === "&nbsp;"){
                this.label.val("");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Put it into a simple javascript file and add it to you template like below:

```
<f:facet name="last">
  <h:outputScript library="default" name="primeFacesPatch.js" />
</f:facet>
```